# beforeRouteLeave and mixin

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am using Vue.js for a CRUD system, tracking a number of different domain classes, such as Customer, Product, etc. I have a validation mixin which I use in each editor component (e.g, CustomerDetail, ProductDetail). Because I would like common behaviour when a user moves away from the page without saving, I'd like to be able to have a method in my validation mixin which I can call in 'beforeRouteLeave'. The method I have come up with is this:

```
checkOnLeave(obj,message,confirmText="Leave",cancelText="Continue Editing",next){
  if (this.isDirty(obj)) { //isDirty checks whether object has been changed
    bootbox.confirm({
      message: message,
      buttons: {
        confirm: {
          label: confirmText,
        },
        cancel: {
          label: cancelText,
        }
      },
      callback: function (result) {
        if (result) {
          next();
        } else {
          next(false);
        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

When I try to use this, though, it doesn't have any idea what to do with 'next'. Clearly this is something from vue-router which it is unaware of. So how can I make my mixin vue-router aware so that I can use this?

Comment: Please show us how you call this function in `beforeRouteLeave`.

Comment: Just tried again and it's working, so there is no problem and it works as I expected it would work. To answer your specific question, it's like this: ` beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
        this.checkOnLeave(this.settings,"Are you sure want to leave the settings editor? You will lose any new or changed data",
          "Leave","Continue Editing",next);}`

Answer (score 0):

Red herring alert. It actually works fine as is - it must have been a delay in compiling which caused the problem before (it happens from time to time with 'npm run dev', the compile occasionally doesn't kick in).